# Loop iteration with await async issue

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, async-await

I have a loop with two await async functions. I would expect that the second function (F2) would fire after completion of the first await function (F1). But the loop continues without even starting F2. F2 fires only after the F1 async function fires.

I have provided tacking functions to follow the flow.

```
        for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
        const S3result = (async () => {
          try {
            console.log ('starting await promise 1' );
            params.Key =  '012/' + 'bob1' + i.toString(); 
            await promiseS3(s3, params);
            console.log ('complete 1st upload');
            params.Key = '012/' +  'bob2' + i.toString();
            console.log ('starting await promise 2' );
            await promiseS3(s3, params);
            console.log('completed 2nd upload');

          } catch (e) {
            console.log (e)
          }
        })()



      const promiseS3 = (s3object,params)  => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log ('start s3 Object promise function');
            s3object.upload(params, function(s3Err, data) { 
                if (s3Err) reject  ('bad S3 call')
            console.log(`File uploaded successfully at ${data.Location}`)
            resolve (data); 
            });

        })
      }
```

I expected F1 to fire, await and then have F2 fire after F1 completes.

This is the output:

starting await promise 1
start s3 Object promise function
starting await promise 1
start s3 Object promise function
starting await promise 1
start s3 Object promise function
starting await promise 1
start s3 Object promise function
starting await promise 1
start s3 Object promise function
after function
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob14
complete 1st upload
starting await promise 2
start s3 Object promise function
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob11
complete 1st upload
starting await promise 2
start s3 Object promise function
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob10
complete 1st upload
starting await promise 2
start s3 Object promise function
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob12
complete 1st upload
starting await promise 2
start s3 Object promise function
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob13
complete 1st upload
starting await promise 2
start s3 Object promise function
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob22
completed 2nd upload
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob21
completed 2nd upload
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob23
completed 2nd upload
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob24
completed 2nd upload
File uploaded successfully at https://filesafe-beta.s3.us-west-1.wasabisys.com/012/bob20
completed 2nd upload

Comment: Having new lines in the log messages would be very helpful -

Comment: Some observations after parsing the output stream; notice that your calls aren't being completed in any certain order. ie, The calls complete in the following order (taking the final digits from the file name) 14, 11, 10, 12, 13, 22, 21, 23, 24, 20. I think what you expect is 10, 20, 11, 21, etc.. Is the issue perhaps that all this for loop is doing is assigning new function variables which are immediately being executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `async` above the `for` loop, not inside the `for` loop.  Remember as soon as an `async` function hits an `await`, it returns a promise immediately.  So, the way you have it structured, you aren't pausing the `for` loop at all.  You're just creating an async function and executing it over and over in each iteration of the loop and nothing is paying any attention to the promise that the `async` function returns.

So, you can do it like this:

```
const S3result = (async () => {
   for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
      try {
        console.log ('starting await promise 1' );
        params.Key =  '012/' + 'bob1' + i.toString(); 
        await promiseS3(s3, params);
        console.log ('complete 1st upload');
        params.Key = '012/' +  'bob2' + i.toString();
        console.log ('starting await promise 2' );
        await promiseS3(s3, params);
        console.log('completed 2nd upload');

      } catch (e) {
        console.log (e)
      }
    }
 })()
```

Also, `S3result` will be a promise that will be resolved when the `for` loop and all the `await` statements inside it are all done.

---

Or, like this where you actually `await` the result of the `async` function in proper view of the `for` loop so it will actually pause the `for` loop (this `for` loop would itself have to be in an `async` function in order to use `await` so there's probably no reason to use the IIFE here.  Letting the `for` loop manage the `await` statements directly as in first option is probably simpler:

```
async function someFunction() {
    for (let i=0; i<5; i++){
        await (async () => {
          try {
            console.log ('starting await promise 1' );
            params.Key =  '012/' + 'bob1' + i.toString(); 
            await promiseS3(s3, params);
            console.log ('complete 1st upload');
            params.Key = '012/' +  'bob2' + i.toString();
            console.log ('starting await promise 2' );
            await promiseS3(s3, params);
            console.log('completed 2nd upload');

          } catch (e) {
            console.log (e)
          }
        })();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that all this for-loop is doing is creating an async function and immediately executing it. So think of it as simultaneously spinning up 5 different instances of the function inside the for-loop.

This is why you get results returned in no particular order. Taking the final digits of the file names, the functions are completing: 14, 11, 10, 12, 13, 22, 21, 23, 24, 20, whereas what I think you expect is 10, 20, 11, 21, ... 14, 24.

To fix this, get rid of the following lines:

```
const S3result = (async () => {
```

and

```
})()
```

Comment: Just to clarify the difference between this answer and jfriend's (posted at the same time), it's just a matter of whether or not this for loop is part of a larger function (my answer), or you want to run it stand-alone (jfriend's answer). The rationale is identical.

Comment: thank you - chill94 and jfriend00!  Excellent answers - it all works now - much appreciated

Comment: @RobertMarlan - Could you mark jfriend's as the accepted answer for future readers (or do the same for mine... but it looks like his is more verbose and descriptive)?